# How to use addEventListener to each individual object key value pair?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a JavaScript object like this -

```
var pages = {
    about: document.querySelector('#about'),
    meta: document.querySelector('#meta'),
    foresight: document.querySelector('#foresight')
}
```

The querySelector is an ID in my navbar, and the HREF id's (where it links to on the page) are listed in the code below -

I'm trying to add an event listener that triggers a smoothscroll method to go to certain areas of my page, I have it working like this -

```
pages.about.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll(document.querySelector('#page1'));
});

pages.meta.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll(document.querySelector('#page2'));
});

pages.foresight.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll(document.querySelector('#page3'));
});
```

I know this is not the most efficient way to write this, and have tried an object forEach method with If conditionals on the keys to smoothscroll to the corresponding page, but it doesn't seem to work right.  Can someone show me the best practice way of writing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could combine the page ID information in your data structure, and use a loop to reuse code:

```
const pages = [
    { button: "about",     page: "page1" },
    { button: "meta",      page: "page2" },
    { button: "foresight", page: "page3" } 
];

for (const { button, page } of pages) {
    document.getElementById(button).addEventListener('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        smoothScroll(document.getElementById(page));
    });
}
```

Comment: I was starting to think an array of objects was better than 1, thank you!  This looks nice and clean! :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it via element attributes:

```js
var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');

for(var i=0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
  
  menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScroll(document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('data-target')));
  });
  
}

function smoothScroll(element) {
  alert('you are scrolling to ' + element.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

```html
<a id="about" href="#" class="menu-item" data-target="#page1">about</a>
<a id="meta" href="#" class="menu-item" data-target="#page2">meta</a>
<a id="foresight" href="#" class="menu-item" data-target="#page3">foresight</a>


<div id="page1">1</div>
<div id="page2">2</div>
<div id="page3">3</div>
```